# Converting URL into NSDATA and Parsing The JSON is right way or not?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

```
NSData *weatherData = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"our URL"]];
NSMutableDictionary *weatherDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:weatherData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

Getiing JSON Data with NSDATA is right way or not?

Comment: Does it work for you or not?

Comment: Yeah, it's Working Perfect But Using NSDATA to converting the url into data instead of NSURLSESSION Class is a right way?

Comment: Using `NSData initWithContentsOfURL` is certainly not the best way. It has many issues.

Comment: ohh thank you for yours information, Then What is the best way?

Comment: As you mentioned, `NSURLSession` is a much better approach.

Comment: can you show some more code, in your http method as GET or POST type

Comment: From starting i'm using AFNetworking and Alamofire for passing JSON,so i don't know about NSURLSession class can you explain about this clearly?@rmaddy

Comment: @lokesh - your request type is GET or POST or else

Comment: @Anub.Karthik my request type is GET

Answer (score 1):

```
For parser JSON better options use:
1) NSURLSession.  
2) AFNetworking .

Using above approve you can handle response  and error (If the request failed or encountered an error )

For  NSURLSession  : 

-(void)getJsonResponseFromServer : (NSString *)urlString  parameter :(NSDictionary*)parameter success : (void (^)(NSDictionary *responseDict))success failure:(void(^)(NSError* error))failure
{

    NSError* error=nil;
    NSURLSession * session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];

    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString: urlString];


    NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:parameter options:0 error:&error];

//Create  URLReques
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                       timeoutInterval:60.0];



    [request addValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
   // [request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];


    // Set Method POST/GET
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    //set Parameter 
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    // Asynchronously Api is hit here

    NSURLSessionDataTask* dataTask=[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {


        if (!error) //If error nil
        {
        //Serialization  data             
            NSDictionary * json  = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

            NSLog(@"json %@",json);

            success(json);
        }
        else
        {
            failure(error);
        }


    }];


    [dataTask resume] ; // Executed task


}
```

Simply call :

```
NSDictionary* paramDict=@{@“paramterName”:@“value”};

    [self getJsonResponseFromServer:@BaseURL parameter:paramDict success:^(NSDictionary *responseDict)
    {

        NSLog(@"responce %@",responseDict);

    } failure:^(NSError *error)
    {
        // error handling here ...

         NSLog(@"error %@",error.description);

    }];
```

for better understanding  [NSURLSession Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/) refer :